Короткое обращение к элементу в CSS
<p class="brown yellow blue">Элемент 1</p>
<p class="red brown green blue">Элемент 2</p>
<p class="yellow blue green">Элемент 3</p>
<p class="silver red yellow">Элемент 4</p>
<p class="brown green red yellow">Элемент 5</p>

Как мне выбрать в ксс второй элемент?? требуется самый коротый вид обращения к этому элементу.

Например, через псевдокласс nth-child


p:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
<p class="brown yellow blue">Элемент 1</p>
<p class="red brown green blue">Элемент 2</p>
<p class="yellow blue green">Элемент 3</p>
<p class="silver red yellow">Элемент 4</p>
<p class="brown green red yellow">Элемент 5</p>



В сниппет показала, как это работает

Нет, это не самое короткое обращение к элементу



.red.blue {
      color:red;
}
<p class="brown yellow blue">Элемент 1</p>
<p class="red brown green blue">Элемент 2</p>
<p class="yellow blue green">Элемент 3</p>
<p class="silver red yellow">Элемент 4</p>
<p class="brown green red yellow">Элемент 5</p>



Так я понял в чем дело, могу сделать так:
Берем первый и последний класс элемента
